# How To Reload Dictionaries On Tableview By Segment Button Click Using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to create a single `tableview` with two button `UISegment control`. I am getting `JSON` response two different `arrays` with two `keys`. For that two keys I created two `buttons`. whenever I click the segment button one, Then `Schools` key values should load on tableview. Whenever I click the second segment button Need to load second Key values `colleges` should reload data on tableview and I want to get table `cell` click to get all keys of values.

My Response :

```
 {
    "Schools" =     {
    };
    "colleges" =     {
        A =         {
            roll_no = 0;
           "name" = "SAMS";
       };
        B =         {
            roll_no = 2;
           "name" = "SANF";        
       };
        C =         {
           roll_no = 3;
           "name" = "UDS";   
        };
   }
```

My Code :

```
- (IBAction)Click_Segmentbutton:(id)sender {

    switch (segment_Button.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:{

            [tableview reloadData];
            NSLog(@"SCHOOLS SELECTED");
            break;}
        case 1:{

            [tableview reloadData];
            NSLog(@"COLLEGES SELECTED");
            break;}
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

     NSIndexPath *indexPath;
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        return [[savedUrl objectForKey:@"Schools"] count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [[savedUrl objectForKey:@"colleges"] count];
    }
}
```

Comment: so whats the issue you are facing as per your code?

Comment: Whenever Button click I cant reload It!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the array count according to the segment Index. So as below.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    if (segment_Button.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        return [[savedUrl objectForKey:@"Schools"] count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [[savedUrl objectForKey:@"colleges"] count];
    }
}
```

Inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method also change your datasource as above.

Comment: ... and in every other tableview datasource method.  It's probably better to keep a reference to the child dictionary currently being used.

Comment: Great answer @DilumN btw how to create cell click to get related dictionary all values! For Example If I click SAMS then It should give rollno and names also.

Comment: After clicking SAMS what's the action do you want to execute? Do you want to Push to new ViewController? or how are you going to show rollno and names??

Comment: No I am listing all the values on tableview. Whenever I click the tableview cell I need to get cell label vealues roll no and names. But now I am showing only names. Not using on tableview cell roll no but want to get for paasing some class!

Comment: Edit your question with cellForRowAtIndexPath method implementation? or create a new question. Btw if this answer helps you marking this as the correct answer will help others in the future

Comment: Sure!Thank you!@DilumN Btw I asked in my scenario " I want to get table cell click to get all keys of values."

Comment: So you have to write your the logic to show all key values inside this method -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {